# Choosing battery replacement for non-retina MacBook Pro

Tags: battery, repair

Is there any objective comparison of third-party batteries for non-retina MacBook Pro (eg mid-2010)? Alternatively, what are the possible strategies to choose which manufacturer to buy from?

Apple officially stopped supplying spare parts for my MacBook Pro Mid 2010 to its authorized repairers, and AFAIK there is no way to buy genuine Apple parts on the market.

Comment: I can offer this...Get a battery with at least a [12 month warranty](https://goo.gl/fmXPQv) which is the same as what Apple offers.  If they are willing to stand behind their product, it's a good thing.

Comment: To anyone voting to close this question, please specify why you choose this or that reason to close. Eg. I don't see how this question is "Too broad" or "Opinion based", please explain.

Comment: The phrase "what are possible strategies" is, in and of itself highly subjective.  That said, are customer product reviews and warranties not sufficient?

Comment: "Possible" != "best" or "recommended", are they? :-)
Are there serious product reviews for third-party replacement batteries? Or you mean customer reviews? @Allan

Comment: "Possible" makes an already subjective question overly broad broad.

Answer (score 7):

I would ensure that you purchase a battery from a reputable online store dealing with Apple products.

For example, the following are some well-regarded sites:

- [Mac Sales](https://eshop.macsales.com/search/battery)
- [Simply Mac](https://simplymac.sg/search?q=battery)
- [RAM City](https://www.ramcity.com.au/upgrade/accessories/laptop-batteries/131413)
- [Macfixit](https://www.macfixit.com.au/apple-laptop-batteries)

By buying from a reputable store you'll be sure to get a battery fit for purpose, regardless of manufacturer. Being reputable means they're only going to sell something that works and they'll stand behind the product they sell, regardless of the brand.

Comment: How does dealing with reputable store help to "choose which manufacturer to buy from" ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. What I mean is that by buying from a reputable store you'll be sure to get a battery fit for purpose, regardless of manufacturer. Being reputable means they're only going to sell something that works. I'll update my answer to make it clearer.